# Elemento da lista zera depois de laço for

Tags: python

Eu criei um vetor e o preenchi com 100 [0] (pois não sei um jeito melhor de fazer isso) e depois disso eu queria alterar esses valores usando um laço `for` dentro de outro laço `for`. Mas o que acontece é que depois do laço de dentro, quando ele sai, todos os valores estão zerados de novo...

Eis o código (tem três prints aí que dá pra ver que dentro do `for` ele muda para o valor que eu quero mas quando termina o `for`, ele volta a ser zero):

```
mediasCa = []

for k in range(0,itera):
    mediasCa.append(0)

for j in range(0,99):
    a = quant
    print(mediasCa[j])
    for i in range(0,itera):
        bola = randint(1,quant)
        if bola < a:
            a -= 1
        else:
            a += 1
    print(mediasCa[i])
    mediasCa[i] = mediasCa[i] + a
    print(mediasCa[i])
```

Comment: Eu ja achei o erro '-', eu to iterando o vetor fora do laço certo... falta um tab =p

Comment: Poste como resposta o código correto.

Comment: Eu nao sei editar direito usando markdown, mas: 

`mediasCa = []
    
    for k in range(0,itera):
        mediasCa.append(0)
    
    
    for j in range(0,99):
        aux = []
        a = quant
        
        for i in range(0,itera):
            bola = randint(1,quant)
            if bola < a:
                a -= 1
            else:
                a += 1
            mediasCa[i] = mediasCa[i] + a`

Comment: Como resposta Pedro, aqui é comentário.

Comment: Desculpa, primeira vez aqui.

Comment: Sem problemas é que quando você já encontrou a solução é sempre bom postar a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O erro era de sintaxe faltou um <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

```
mediasCa = []    
for k in range(0,itera):
    mediasCa.append(0)
for j in range(0,99):
    aux = []
    a = quant
    for i in range(0,itera):
        bola = randint(1,quant)
        if bola < a:
            a -= 1
        else:
            a += 1
        mediasCa[i] = mediasCa[i] + a
```